# Forming Combinations of Quadrilaterals From Heptagon

Tags: combinations, polygons

What is the formula for finding Number of  Quadrilaterals from heptagon or any other regular polygon above pentagon for that matter?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "number of quadrilaterals from heptagon". Maybe you could show us "number of quadrilaterals from pentagon", with examples and explanation, and then we could figure out what you mean.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think he means something like: given heptagon $ABCDEFG$, how many quadrilaterals can be formed from the set of vertices $\{A,B,C,D,E,F,G\}$. In which case, the answer would seem to be $7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4$.

Comment: Yes I mean exactly that..

Comment: @DavidH, $7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4$ is only right if you count ABCD as being different ffrom BCDA and CDAB and DABC and DCBA and so on.

Comment: If that's what you mean, khan, please edit your question so it says so. People shouldn't have to go through the comments to understand the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson True. I probably should have mentioned that, but at the time I was more focused on trying to pin down what the heck this question was trying to ask. But at least it seems like I accomplished that much. :)

Comment: You also have to avoid crossing the sides. Don't count selections such as ACBD because that's a figure of 8--a double triangle--not a quadrilateral. Always move forward (say clockwise) and "don't pass Go."

Comment: @Graham, it's a quadrilateral by some definitions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, a **much** simpler way is to just count the ways to select any four of the seven (or whatever) vertices.   $\binom 7 4$ for a heptagon, or $\binom n 4$ for any polygon of $n$ sides/vertices.

The following is overly complex, and I really don't know what I was thinking at the time.

---

For a heptagon there are 7 vertices.  That gives seven starting points, label them $A,B,C,D,E,F,G$, moving clockwise.

We need to account for rotational symmetry.  If we choose any four vertice $WXYZ$, that is rotationally equivalent to three others: $XYZW$, $YZWX$, and $ZWXY$.  The only difference being from were we start.

If we select any of the seven as a starting point, say $A$ for convenience, there are then four points, moving clockwise, we can use for the diagonally-opposite vertix of the quadrilateral. That's $C,D,E,F$.  Now as $C$ is two vertices clockwise from $A$, and $F$ is five; that's equivalent to choosing a number, $y \in [2..5]$.

If we choose $C$ then the remaining two points on our quadrilateral have to be $B$ and a choice of $D,E,F,G$.  If we choose $D$ then the other two are a choice of $B,C$ and a choice of $E,F,G$.  Et cetera.  Again this is simply choosing numbers of vertices clockwise from $A$, which are $x\in [1..y-1]$ and $z \in [y+1..6]$

So we count by the summation: $$C(7) = \frac{7}{4} \sum_{y = 2}^4 \sum_{x = 1}^{y-1} \sum_{z=y+1}^6 1 = \frac{7}{4} \sum_{y = 2}^4 (y-1)(6-y) = 35$$

Thus there are 35 distinct quadrilaterals that are can be formed by selecting 4 vertices of a heptagon.

---

So in general you wish to find: $C(n) = \frac n 4 \sum\limits_{y=2}^{n-2} (y-1)(n-1-y)$

Reindexing, that is: $C(n) = \frac 4 2 \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-3} ((n-2)k - k^2)$

Applying the formula for $\sum\limits_{k=1}^N k = \frac{N(N+1)}2$ and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^N k^2 = \frac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}{6}$, we have:

$$C(n) = \frac{n}{4}\left((n-2)\frac{(n-3)(n-2))}{2}-\frac{(n-3)(n-2)(2n-5)}{6}\right)$$

Which simplifies to: $$C(n) = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{24}$$

---

Pentagon: $C(5) = 5$, Hexagon: $C(6)=15$, Heptagon: $C(7)=35$, Octagon: $C(8)=70$, and so on.

Comment: Thats very well and nicely explained.

Comment: Your final formula is just $n\choose4$, which suggests a much simpler way to get there: any choice of 4 vertices specifies a unique (non-self-crossing) quadrilateral.